# Keep XTick but write out XTickLabel only in loglog plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot in loglog system with `xlim([15 350])`.
I want to keep all XTick lines for the grid, but write only the following values on the label: `x=20,50,80,100,200`.

I've tried `set(gca,'XTick',[20,50,80,100,200])`, then the intermediate ticks (and so the grid-lines) are removed. Using `set(gca,'XTickLabel',[20,50,80,100,200])` doesn't work either. (I've seen an example where two Xtick series are defined, labeled separately, then merged, but couldn't get working for my case, not even sure if possible.)

Would be grateful for some solutions here, this simple thing has been driving me crazy! :)

Thanks!
also tried something like removing all XtickLabels, create a new

Comment: I assume you'd like to keep the minor ticks of the log log plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set your ticks to where you want them, including *minor* ticks.
Then use a cell array containing a value for *major* ticks and an empty array for *minor* ticks:

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [10:10:90, 100:100:400]);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {[], 20, [], [], 50, [], [], 80, [], 100, 200});
```

Comment: If I do that they are never on the right place. Each number is on every 10th tick (that is 1e0, 1e1, 1e2, etc.). Tried playing around with adding/removing empty arrays, but didn't manage to get it right.

Just tried to look up if there is an 'XMinorTickLabel' option, but it seems not.

Comment: If you want total control over your ticks and labels, you need to set the `XTick` first, and then set the `XTickLabel` leaving an empty array in place of any "minor" ticks where you don't want text to appear.

Comment: How simple! Thanks a lot!
Just to have the solution here: 


`set(gca,'XTick',[10:10:90,100:100:400])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{[],20,[],[],50,[],[],80,[],100,200});`

Comment: @tkekesi I incorporated the final solution in my answer, which you can accept if it solved your problem.